# How to make procedural very large/detailed volcano

Tags: modeling, procedural

I was looking for making a large scale Volcanic eruption, the tutorials I found are either too manual on the train generation or they are too detailed via sculpting that it's simply impractical for animation. If you guys can point out simple ways to make volcanic mountain and it's lava, it would be very helpful.

PS - the lava doesn't have to flow, just glowing. And scale/detail is what I'm looking for. Thank you in advance!
Edit: here's the reference render I'm trying to make procedurally
[image: enter image descriptionhere]

Comment: Please add an image of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Added the reference render

Comment: Could you show what have you done so far? I'm not sure to understand where are you stuck. You said it's an animation, but also that tha lava doesn't have to flow. Could you clarify which elements are in motion?

Comment: It's a Pixar Style animation. The lava doesn't have to look realistic. I just need it to look like the one on the render. You can neglect the various simulations

Comment: I am not sure what makes you think there is a "simple" way to do this? It seems like in order to get a good result - even cartoony in style - you'd have to sculpt and put in a few hours of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A volcano can be approximated using an ANT landscape and a shader.

[image]

---

Procedure: (tested on Blender 2.79b)

1. Create the landscape using an ANT mesh and choose the 'vulcano' preset. Note you may need to enable the add-on for ANT in 'user preferences'

[image]
[image]

2. Switch to cycles render.
3. Create a new material for the landscape.
4. Add the following shader. This shader works by adding a red glow to the creases in the landscape using the pointiness property of the geometry. The height is used to control how far down the landscape the 'lava' flows.

[image]

---

Blend file with an example is available here [image]